# How to find all dates between 2 dates in django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I want to find all dates between 2 dates
the first date is **unique_dates[0]** the value of unique_dates[0] is **2021-08-30** and the second date is **datetime.date.today()**

```
unique_dates = list({a.date for a in attendances})
date = datetime.date.today()
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import datetime

real_date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(unique_dates[0]), '%Y-%m-%d')
real_date2 = datetime.datetime.today()
date_range =  real_date2 - real_date1
dates = list()
for days in range(1,date_range.days+1):
    dates.append((real_date1 + datetime.timedelta(days)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') )

print( dates)
```

output:

```
['31/08/2021', '01/09/2021', '02/09/2021', '03/09/2021']
```

Comment: @PathParakh, if real_date1 is datetome.date only insert value in real_date1, `real_date1 = your_data`